# How to get the matrix from an alphanumeric range

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some Excel stuff in JavaScript and wonder, if there are any "native" ways to get the matrix between the alphanumeric values. The output of `E12..F14` should be something like this: `E12, E13, E14, F12, F13, F14`.

Comment: Do not try and bend the spoon, there is no spoon ......

Comment: Then you'll see, that it is not the spoon that bends, it is only yourself.